# PHP unlink woes

Tags: php, filesystems, unlink

I am using php function unlink() as you most probably assumed but it seems to be giving me a false negative... It gives me this warning:

> Warning: unlink(/home/blackboa/public_html/classes/lib/test.lang) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/blackboa/public_html/modules/lang_manage/main.php on line 41

But the file does get deleted.

Here is the php code for the specific function:

```
function delete_lang_file($file){
   if(preg_match('#\.lang#', $file) && !preg_match('#blank\.lang#', $file)){
        unlink(CLASSES_PATH."lib/".$file);
   }
}
```

There is no existing file handlers when this function is executed however file_get_contents() and an fopen() fwrtie() and fclose() set are used in other functions which are never called in the same execution of unlink().

Is there anything I am doing wrong, forward slash instead of backslash maybe?

Thanks,

Fraser K

Comment: What makes you think it's getting deleted?

Comment: As Wooble sort of mentions, are you absolutely sure the file exists _before_ your call to unlink? This error message, coming from unlink does not usually lie.

Comment: maybe wrap   if(file_exists()){} around your unlink. And log what it's doing if need be.

Comment: The script that that is in allows you to view, create, edit, and delete .lang files. You and not delete a file if php does not read it as I am using a directory reading function to list all the files, then you can select whether or not to delete it. I also have checked to see if the file exist prior to and after 'deleting' it. Yes it does exist before, no it does not after.

Comment: @stefgosselin will try that and let you know.

Comment: okay wtf.... when i add the file_exists() to the if function i don't get the error? Because i did not change any other code.

Comment: Maybe you're calling the delete function twice.

Comment: ^thats what i was thinking... but i couldn't see how it would.

Comment: check if something possibly calls delete_lang_file() twice (:

Comment: @BeingSimpler this would be my guess as well.